# Bell test results question

Tags: bell-experiment

I created two Qiskit programs to do a Bell test for hidden variables. In one test, the program does 100 shots for each of nine circuits -- a total of 900 shots. The result is always close to 0.50 as predicted. In the other test, the program creates a random list of 1000 circuits and does one shot on each of the circuits. On this test, the result varies greatly depending on what the random list of 1000 circuits is. It can go from around 0.8 to 0.3.
Is this normal behavior? If so, how can I fix it? When I try to do many more shots with the random circuit scheme, it's too much for the simulator.

Here's the code I used to create the circuits:

````
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit


def get_circuit(angle_left, angle_right):
    circ = QuantumCircuit(2)
    circ.h(0)
    circ.cnot(0, 1)
    circ.x(1)
    circ.barrier()
    circ.ry(angle_left, 0)
    circ.ry(angle_right, 1)
    circ.measure_all()
    display(circ.draw('latex'))
    return circ


from math import pi

northwest = pi / 6
southwest = 5 * pi / 6
east = 9 * pi / 6
directions = [northwest, southwest, east]

nine_circs = []
for dir_left in directions:
    for dir_right in directions:
        nine_circs.append(get_circuit(dir_left, dir_right))



import random

circ_counts = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
random_circs = []
for i in range(1000):
    circ_number = random.randint(0, 8)
    random_circs.append(nine_circs[circ_number])
    circ_counts[circ_number] += 1
print('Circuit counts: ', end='')
print(circ_counts)
print('nw nw | nw se | nw e | se nw | se se | se e | e nw | e sw | e e')



from qiskit import IBMQ, transpile
from qiskit.providers.ibmq.managed import IBMQJobManager

provider = IBMQ.load_account()
device = provider.get_backend('ibmq_qasm_simulator')
# Use a quantum computer with at least two qubits

ranndom_circs = transpile(random_circs, backend=device)
manager = IBMQJobManager()
job = manager.run(random_circs, backend=device, shots=1)
result = job.results()
print('finished')



print('started')
disagree = 0
total = 0
for circ in random_circs:
    output = result.get_counts(circ)
    total += 1
    # print(output, end=' ')
    if '01' in output or '10' in output:
        disagree += 1
    if disagree % 50 == 0:
        print(disagree / total)
print('\nProbability of disagreement: '
      + str(disagree / len(random_circs)))
```
````

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add more detail to the question to make it easier to understand. What are the circuits you are running exactly? The numerical result you refer to is the average number of times you win the nonlocal game?

Comment: @Rammus - I added some code. Do you need to see more of the experiment code?

Comment: don't you need a hadamard on qubit 0 before the cnot? Otherwise you won't get any entanglement...

Comment: Wow! I can't believe that I omitted that gate. I would have caught it if the draw function was displaying anything, but it wasn't. Why not? Shouldn't I see a circuit diagram whenever the function is called?

Comment: @bburd do `display(circ.draw())` for jupyter notebook

Comment: Thanks. Why does circ.draw() without display () work in some cases in a notebook and not others?

Comment: @bburd because that is inside a function, if you do the draw function multiple time without display() it will only show the last draw, not repeatly draw in a cell output.

Comment: I added the missing H gate, and I'm still getting wide variations in the probabilities depending on the number of randomly generated gates of each kind. So now I've edited my original post and added all my code. What stupid mistake am I still making?